# Workflow that Creates Subsites throwing Forbidden Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I have 150 copies of the same site collection that have a Subsite creator workflow. It works on all of them, but today I spun up a new one that will not work. I get the following results (with domain redacted):

• Making call to get Template ID at: https://[Site]/_api/web/getavailablewebtemplates(1033)?$filter=Title%20eq%20%27Campaign Site Template%27&$select=Name

• Retrieved Template Id for template name Campaign Site Template: {0DC4AF31-DB8F-4DB9-B52A-DC0FD28F9DE6}#Campaign Site Template

• Making call to add site at: https://[site]/_api/web/webinfos/add

**• Completed call to Add Site with response code: Forbidden**

The bolded is throwing a forbidden, but I have no idea why or how to diagnose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the two points below:

1. Make sure your Form Digest value is correct through using $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() to get the form digest value.
2. Make sure you have the relevant permissions.

Reference:

[How to refresh the Request Digest value in JavaScript](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm seeing a couple posts about the SharePoint Online Rest API having some issues.